# Do I need to call context.dispose when adding the dbcontext with DI?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET CORE web API using EF. I'm wondering if I need to manually dispose my dbcontext. When adding your dbcontext with DI, it is my understanding that this gets added as a scoped service that recreates the context for each request.

I've registered it as a service:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<FeedbackContext>();
}
```

And used in controller like this:

```
public Controller(FeedbackContext context)
{
    _context = context;
}
```

Do I need to dispose the context in my controller like this:

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        _context.Dispose();
    }
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}
```

Or is this handled for me?

Comment: 1. One has to understand what structure you have been following for the Context creation, ideally it should dispose at the creation and 2.  public void Dispose()
    {
        if(_context!= null) _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    } this would be enough and less confusing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You do not need to call `Dispose`. ASP.NET Core will do that for you. Using `AddDbContext`, the context will be scoped to the request. All scoped objects will be disposed when the request finishes.

In fact, you can see this for yourself by overriding `Dispose` and putting a breakpoint inside it or logging something.

```
public class FeedbackContext : DbContext
{
    public override void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Had a hunch that was the case. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Should be noted that this is only valid if you register is at scoped or transient (transients implementing IDisposable get disposed too). `AddDbScope` with singleton life time won't be disposed obviously

Comment: In case anyone else finds their way here, `AddDbContext` in more recent versions calls `DisposeAsync`...if you need to override, that probably needs to be overriden as well.